# Set one viewport in an XPages Application with a bootstrap theme

Tags: xpages

I want to set the meta tag viewport in an XPage application. Therefore I use a theme which needs to extend the Bootstrap3.2.0_flat theme. As a result I get two viewport tags in the final html. But two viewport tags do not make any sense.

Theme:

```
<theme extends="Bootstrap3.2.0_flat" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="platform:/plugin/com.ibm.designer.domino.stylekits/schema/stylekit.xsd" >
    <resources>
        <metaData>
            <name>viewport</name>
            <content>user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi</content>
        </metaData>
    </resources>    
</theme>
```

html:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
```

It seems the first viewport is derived form the theme. Is there any way to override it? Am thinking of mode="override" as used in controls. Or is the first viewport a result of something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `<control>` properties in a theme you can use an `override="true"` attribute to specify that it should override the 'default' value. I don't think you can do that with a `<metaData>` tag.

What you can do however:

- Create a new Bootstrap 3.2.0 base theme in your application that is based on the `Bootstrap3.2.0_flat` theme. The source for that can be found in the [Extension Library](https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary/blob/002179f4e755795c3f00510da72843ecb0c2357f/extlib/lwp/product/runtime/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.xsp.theme.bootstrap/src/com/ibm/xsp/theme/bootstrap/themes/Bootstrap3.2.0_flat.theme).
- In that theme you then set the correct value of the `<metaData>` tag.
- In your current theme, you replace the `extends="Bootstrap3.2.0_flat"` with the name of your the theme you just created/ copied.

(oh and remember that in the latest Extension Library version, the Bootstrap3.2.0 theme has been renamed)